# How to make triangular pyramids on each face of an original triangular pyramid

Tags: modeling, workflow

How could I make triangular pyramids on each face of an original triangular pyramid.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If I didn't misunderstand your question, you can switch to **Edit Mode**, Make sure all faces are selected by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to poke faces, which will create a vertex on each face. Tweak **Poke Offset** value in its setting panel down to the left-hand Tool Shelf.(or press <kbd>F6</kbd> to call a separate popup).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, if I can just know now how to create the original triangular pyramid. Let me know what I can do in return even if you don't know how to do this!

Comment: @user1802 Do you mean a regular tetrahedron? There are several ways to make such shape. Typically, you may enable an addon called [Regular Solids](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_Solid), which can make one much easier.

Comment: You can add a Mesh Circle and set Vertices to 3, fill type to Triangle Fan. Move the center vert up, deselect, select the 3 bottom verts and make face for your triangular pyramid. Then poke faces.